# Find all matrices $A \in \mathcal M_n(\Bbb C)$ such that: for every matrix $B \in \mathcal M_n(\Bbb C)$, there is $b \in \Bbb C$ such that $ABA=bA$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As it turns out $A^2$ is not necessarily $O_n$. So, as pointed out by the comments, the answer should be $O_n$ and all rank-$1$ matrices.

Comment: No, $A^2$ doesn't have to be zero. Consider $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}$ for instance. The solution set should be comprised of the zero matrix and all rank-$1$ matrices.

Comment: Yeah you are right, if $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}$, $A^2$ is not $O_n$, yet it satisfies the condition.... I'll change the statement of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an incomplete (possibly buggy) sketch of a solution, which yields in fact $A = 0$ or $A$ of rank $1$, as stated by @user1551 in their comment. So perhaps there is a more conceptual approach here (there is, see below).

Note that the property holds replacing $A$ with a conjugate.

Take first $B$ to be the identity to get $A^{2} = b_{0} A$ for some $b_{0}$. So the eigenvalues of $A$ are roots of $x^{2} - b_{0} x$, i.e. they can only be $0$ or $b_{0}$.

If $b_{0} = 0$, then $A^{2} = 0$. $A= 0$ is course a solution. If $A^{2} = 0 \ne A$, a single $2 \times 2$ Jordan block is allowed here. This is because $A$ must have rank one, as one sees by taking $B$ of rank one.

If $b_{0} \ne 0$, then the minimal polynomial of $A$ has distinct roots, so that $A$ can be put into diagonal form as a block matrix
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & X\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $X$ is a scalar matrix with $b_{0} \ne 0$ on the diagonal, and the stated condition will still hold for $A$ in this form. Enforcing the property for $B$ a matrix which is all zero, except for a $1$ in the $(n, n)$ entry, we see that $X$ must be a $1 \times 1$ matrix $[b_{0}]$, and this (i.e. $A$ a diagonal rank one matrix) should be a solution.

---

The conceptual approach should be the following. Take $B$ of rank one, to see that $A \ne 0$ must have rank one. Distinguish the case when all eigenvalues of $A$ are zero, and when there is a single non-zero eigenvalue $b_{0}$. In the latter case, choose a basis $v_{1}, \dots , v_{n}$ such that $v_{1} A = b_{0} v_{1}$, and $v_{i} A = 0$ for $i > 1$. In the former case, choose the basis so that $v_{1} A = v_{2}$, and $v_{i} A = 0$ for $i > 1$. The property is then immediately seen to hold.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the zero matrix is a solution. We claim the nonzero solutions are precisely those rank-one matrices.

Suppose $A\ne0$. Then there exists some vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $Au$ and $v^TA$ are nonzero. Let $B=uv^T$. By assumption, $(Au)(v^TA)=ABA=bA$ for some scalar $b$. Since $Au$ and $v^TA$ are nonzero, $b$ must be nonzero. It follows that $A=\frac1b(Au)(v^TA)$ has rank one.

Conversely, if $A$ has rank one, then $A=xy^T$ for some vectors $x$ and $y$. Hence $ABA=x(y^TBx)y^T=(y^TBx)xy^T=(y^TBx)A=bA$ where $b=y^TBx$.